buttons in dialog flow cx
How can we align 2 buttons side by side dialog flow cx horizontally?
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "button",
        "text": "button1"
      },
      {
        "type": "button",
        "text": "button2"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

this configuration shows 2 buttons one below the another . Is their any way to give custom styling in dialog flow cx or any other way of achieving this behaviour


Hello @Sim, could you check this documentation ? Let me know if this helps you or not.

nope have followed this documentation only for the creation of rich content .Do you have any idea @DhirajSingh?

It is not possible through the standard JSON offered by dialog flow . It can be achieved using custom component. Below are the details of how I achieved it :
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/buttons-in-dialog-flow-cx/m-p/845857#M10864
